# how to get data from text file and rewrite to another from

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

- hello beautiful people so i have a text file like this :
- user = user447
- pass = 455555az
- type = registred
- date = 1 year

  **and i want to read the file and rewrite it like this**

> 1. user|pass|type|date,
>    line by line,
>    i tried so many ways , i seem stuck since i have to deal with 1    million account

```
with open(file, "r") as f:
 data = []
 for line in f:
    key = line.rstrip('\n').split('=')
    key1 = key[1:2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to read the entire file all at once, instead, you can just read it in parts and write as you read (note the `with` block is used for *two* `open()` context managers, though you can nest them inside each other just as easily)

```py
with open(source) as fh_src, open(destination, "w") as fh_dest:
    block = []
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fh_src, 1):
        # .split("=", 1)[-1] captures everything after the first =
        # this is also an opportunity to verify the key
        block.append(line.split("=", 1)[-1].strip())
        if len(block) == 4:
            fh_dest.write("{}|{}|{}|{}\n".format(*block))
            block = []  # reset block after each write
```

it's definitely worth creating some safeguards, however!

- checking if lines really start with some key if you have a set of known keys or have some you intend to omit, or if you have some dynamic set of keys (say some users have a collection of previous password hashes, or different comments)
- checking `if block` at the end (it should be cleared and write!)
- checking `=` is really in each line or that any comments are kept or discarded
- opening `"w"` will remove `destination` if it exists already (perhaps from a botched previous run), which may be undesirable

(`lineno` is only included to simplify discovering bad lines)